# How to reshaping Data in Javascript from array to object without losing some of the data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add the key to each so that I can be able to easy make a multi scatter plot in d3. . I am not sure how to do it.

EDIT: TO CLARIFY what I meant.

Data:

```
var dataOriginal = {
  Apples: [{"A":4,"B":null,"C":null,"D":2},  {"A":5,"B":null,"C":3,"D":2}],
  Oranges: [{"A":3,"B":1,"C":4,"D":4.3}],
  Jackfruit: [{"A":5,"B":4,"C":4,"D":3}],
  Avocado: [{"A":null,"B":33,"C":2,"D":9.66}],
  Pomegranate: [{"A":5,"B":3.5,"C":null,"D":6}]
}
```

Function:

```
const data = Object.keys(dataOriginal).map((key) => {
  const temp = {...dataOriginal[key]};
  temp.key = key;
  return temp;
});
```

Results:

```
0:
0: {A: 4, B: null, C: null, D: 2}
1: {A: 5, B: null, C: 3, D: 2}
key: "Apples"
__proto__: Object
1:
0: {A: 3, B: 1, C: 4, D: 4.3}
key: "Oranges"
__proto__: Object
2:
0: {A: 5, B: 4, C: 4, D: 3}
key: "Jackfruit"
__proto__: Object
3:
0: {A: null, B: 33, C: 2, D: 9.66}
key: "Avocado"
__proto__: Object
4: {0: {…}, key: "Pomegranate"}
```

Desired results

```
: {A: 4, B: null, C: null, D: 2, key: "Apples"}
1: {A: 3, B: 1, C: 4, D: 4.3, key: "Oranges"}
2: {A: 5, B: 4, C: 4, D: 3, key: "Jackfruit"}
3: {A: null, B: 33, C: 2, D: 9.66, key: "Avocado"}
4: {A: 5, B: 3.5, C: null, D: 6, key: "Pomegranate"}
5: {A:5,B:null,C:3,D:2, key: "Apples"}
```

Comment: do you want to add the nested properties by key?

Comment: `const temp = {...dataOriginal[key][0]};` is specifying the first item in those arrays.  you need to loop through `dataOriginal[key]` if you want all items

Comment: @mrben522 I have edited  to make more sense. sorry

Comment: @NinaScholz yes. I have edited to add more context

Answer (score 2):

The reason why {"A":5,"B":null,"C":3,"D":2} is missed is because, index 0 is hardcoded in the code.
const temp = {...dataOriginal[key][0]};

Alternate solution:

```js
var dataOriginal = {
  Apples: [{"A":4,"B":null,"C":null,"D":2},  {"A":5,"B":null,"C":3,"D":2}],
  Oranges: [{"A":3,"B":1,"C":4,"D":4.3}],
  Jackfruit: [{"A":5,"B":4,"C":4,"D":3}],
  Avocado: [{"A":null,"B":33,"C":2,"D":9.66}],
  Pomegranate: [{"A":5,"B":3.5,"C":null,"D":6}]
}

const myData =[]
Object.keys(dataOriginal).map((key) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < dataOriginal[key].length; i++) {
    myData.push({...dataOriginal[key][i], key})
  }
})

console.log(myData)
```

Comment: This was very helpful, was just looking for this solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce the object to get a single object with added values.

```js
const
    addByKey = array => array.reduce((a, b) => {
        Object.entries(b).forEach(([k, v]) => a[k] = (a[k] || 0) + v);
        return a;
    }, {}),
    dataOriginal = { Apples: [{ A: 4, B: null, C: null, D: 2 }, { A: 5, B: null, C: 3, D: 2 }], Oranges: [{ A: 3, B: 1, C: 4, D: 4.3 }], Jackfruit: [{ A: 5, B: 4, C: 4, D: 3 }], Avocado: [{ A: null, B: 33, C: 2, D: 9.66 }], Pomegranate: [{ A: 5, B: 3.5, C: null, D: 6 }] }
    data = Object.keys(dataOriginal).map((key) => ({ ...addByKey(dataOriginal[key]), key }));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For getting single object with same keys, you could map the objects, add the key and get a flat array.

```js
const
    dataOriginal = { Apples: [{ A: 4, B: null, C: null, D: 2 }, { A: 5, B: null, C: 3, D: 2 }], Oranges: [{ A: 3, B: 1, C: 4, D: 4.3 }], Jackfruit: [{ A: 5, B: 4, C: 4, D: 3 }], Avocado: [{ A: null, B: 33, C: 2, D: 9.66 }], Pomegranate: [{ A: 5, B: 3.5, C: null, D: 6 }] }
    data = Object
        .keys(dataOriginal)
        .flatMap(key => dataOriginal[key].map(o => ({ ...o, key })));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your results are the same is the "incorrect" example in the question. OP is looking for each object in the original data to be merged into a new one-dimensional array.

Comment: I am understanding your answer. Do you mind explaining. I have also editted the question to add more clarity.

Comment: @Kabooki, which one do you want?